# Error in dart code final Color _color; TextSection (this._color);

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

when I'm trying to define colour in dart code  `final Color _color;    TextSection (this._color);`
it gives me an error. do anyone know how to fix this error.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class Textsection extends StatelessWidget {

   final Color _color;

  TextSection (this._color);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color:_color,
        ),
        child:Text('hi')

    );
  }

 /* @override
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => super.noSuchMethod(invocation);*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class name is `Textsection` where `section` is lowercase but your constructor is named `TextSection` with an uppercase `Section`.
Try renaming your class to `TextSection` so it matches your constructor name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the class constructor first then you are able to use this, I hope this will work for you.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Textsection extends StatelessWidget {

  final Color? color;
  const Textsection({Key? key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

 

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color:color,
        ),
        child:Text('hi')

    );
  }

/* @override
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => super.noSuchMethod(invocation);*/
}
```